# Azure User Assigned Identity fails to read AzureAD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to get an Azure AD group information in a Powershell script inside a function app. I am using the below command.

```
Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName avktestx4054ce26FCA
```

But, if throws an error saying "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". What is the minimum permissions required for executing this command. Currently it has Microsoft Graph "Read all groups" permissions.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command essentially calls the `Azure AD Graph` not `Microsoft Graph`, so the permission of Microsoft Graph will not take effect, what you need here is the *Application permission*(not *Delegated permission*) `Directory.Read.All` in `Azure AD Graph`. From your description, I suppose you have known the way to grant the API permission to the User Assigned Identity, not repeat here.

Another way is to give the [Azure AD admin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) to the User Assigned Identity, e.g. [`Directory Readers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers), this role's permission is less than `Directory.Read.All` above, and AAD Graph is a Supported legacy API, so the second way is recommended. After giving the role, wait for a while to take effect, then it will work fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joy! I tried the first option Directory.Read.All and it did not work. But the second option worked!

Comment: @ArunVijay The first one will also work, you may not do that correctly.